# AngularJS - force render / rerender / compile a ng-repeated div inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a div which uses ng-repeat.

I start with a few items in an array.

I would like to force the first item to render before the next item is rendered. The reason for this is because of the dependency on height of each div

Is there a way to do that?

```
<div class='listOne'>
    <div ng-repeat='item in listOne'>{{item}}</div>
</div>
<div class='listTwo'>
    <div ng-repeat='item in listTwo'>{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myList = ['something', 'stuff', 'someOtherthing'];
var listOne = [];
var listTwo = [];

// decide which list to insert into
function decideListBasedOnHeight() { // returns array
    var listOneElement = // reference to listOne element
    var listTwoElement = // reference to listTwo element
    if (listOneElement.offsetHeight > listTwoElement.offsetHeight ) // the height here is zero for both
       return listTwo;
    return listOne;
}

forEach (myList, function(value) {
    decideBasedOnHeight().push(value);
});
```

Example of problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/XxJTzNlnQrB7S7tQ0PBL?p=preview
Second example: http://plnkr.co/edit/3pzpsgmQ0vIM1e6nuEQG?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm, nice question.

You could not forEach an array but push it step by step via directive. See

```
<div ng-contoller="ctrl">
    <div class='listOne'>
        <div ng-repeat='item in listOne' count-height-and-push-next="listOneHeight">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class='listTwo'>
        <div ng-repeat='item in listTwo' count-height-and-push-next="listTwoHeight">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

.directive('countHeightAndPushNext', function(){
   return{
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: true,
       link: function(scope, element, attrs){
           scope[attrs.countHeightAndPushNext] += element[0].outerHeigth;
           scope.pushItem();
       }
   };

})

.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.myList = ['something', 'stuff', 'someOtherthing'];
    $scope.listOne = [];
    $scope.listOneHeight = 0;
    $scope.listTwo = [];
    $scope.listTwoHeight = 0;

    var nextPushIndex = 0;
    $scope.pushItem = function(){
        if($scope.listOneHeight > $scope.listTwoHeight){
             $scope.listTwo.push($scope.myList[nextPushIndex])
        }else{
             $scope.listOne.push($scope.myList[nextPushIndex]);
        }
        nextPushIndex++;
    };
    $scope.pushItem();
});
```

I really don't like tight coupling in this example and it absolutely needs to be refactored and remastered, but that's just an idea. Probably not the best one, but it should work. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. I find that using append also works http://plnkr.co/edit/UyRS0clrCwDpSrYgBsXS?p=preview

Comment: I tested this out quite a bit recently and I find that it does not work.

Comment: [Here's a working version](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4824/). But i still don't like tight coupling. That's just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this again, but it still doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4873/ I updated the fiddle, it seems to be doing the calculations, but it is not really working correctly.

Comment: My workaround for this entire ordeal is to use a formula to guesstimate the height of a div dependent on the length of the text, it's about 90% accurate and is only noticeable after hundreds of items in each column. Thanks again gopacrate

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4874/), i've added `getAbsoluteHeight` to count height including margins and added zero $timeout to the directive to give browser a chance to render element correctly and achieve it's real size, before adding the next one.

Comment: String length - is not very good because letters have different width. It would be affordable in case of monospace font, but that's rare case.